# Pattern-matching syntax not Constructor application syntax

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Given a two-place data constructor, I can partially apply it to one argument then apply that to the second. Why can't I use the same syntax for pattern matching?

```
data Point = MkPoint Float Float

x = 1.0 :: Float; y = 2.0 :: Float

thisPoint = ((MkPoint x) y)          -- partially apply the constructor

(MkPoint x1 y1) = thisPoint          -- pattern match OK

((MkPoint x2) y2) = thisPoint        -- 'partially apply' the pattern, but rejected: parse error at y2

((MkPoint x3 y3)) = thisPoint        -- this accepted, with double-parens
```

Why do I want to do that? I want to grab the constructor and first arg as an as-pattern, so I can apply it to a different second arg. (Yes the work-round in this example is easy. Realistically I have a much more complex pattern, with several args of which I want to split out the last.):

```
(mkPx@(MkPoint x4) y4) = thisPoint   -- also parse error

thatPoint = mkPx (y4 * 2)
```

Comment: The Language Report (2010) § 3.17.1 says "The arity of a constructor must match the number of sub-patterns associated with it; one cannot match against
a partially-applied constructor." My LHS overall is not partially-applied.

Comment: Hm, after writing an answer, I guess there's an ambiguity here. Are you asking why the Report was written as it was, or are you asking what part of the Report rules this out?

Comment: Yes I'm asking which part rules it out. I can see matching needs a fully-applied constr; and that's what I'm giving it at 'outer' level in the pattern. It's fine to bind a var to a partially-applied constr: `let mkPx = (MkPoint 1.2) in ...`. Why can't the As-pattern bind same way?

Comment: Okay, I have added a section to my answer describing the mechanism by which the Report prevents this.

Answer (score 7):

I think there's no fundamental reason to prevent this kind of match.

Certainly it wouldn't do to allow you to write

```
f (MkPoint x1) = x1
```

and have that match a partially-applied constructor, i.e. a function. So, one reason to specify it as it was specified here is for simplicity: the RHS of an `@` has to be a pattern. Simple, easy to parse, easy to understand. (Remember, the very first origins of the language were to serve as a testbed for PL researchers to tinker. Simple and uniform is the word of the day for that purpose.) `MkPoint x1` isn't a pattern, therefore `mkPx@(MkPoint x1)` isn't allowed.

I suspect that if you did the work needed to carefully specify what is and isn't allowed, wrote up a proposal, and volunteered to hack on the parser and desugarer as needed, the GHC folks would be amenable to adding a language extension. Seems like a lot of work for not much benefit, though.

Perhaps record update syntax will scratch your itch with much less effort.

```
data Point = MkPoint {x, y :: Float}
m@(MkPoint { x = x5 }) = m { x = x5 + 1 }
```

You also indicate that, aside from the motivation, you wonder what part of the Report says that the pattern you want can't happen. The relevant grammar productions from the Report are [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17):

> ```
> pat   →   lpat
>
> lpat  →   apat
>       |   gcon apat1 … apatk      (arity gcon  =  k, k ≥ 1)
>
> apat  →   var [ @ apat]           (as pattern)
>       |   gcon                    (arity gcon  =  0)
>       |   ( pat )                 (parenthesized pattern)
> ```

(I have elided some productions that don't really change any of the following discussion.)

Notice that as-patterns must have an *apat* on their right-hand side. *apat*s are 0-arity constructors (in which case it's not possible to partially apply it) or parenthesized *lpat*s. The *lpat* production shown above indicates that for constructors of arity *k*, there must be exactly *k* *apat* fields. Since `MkPoint` has arity 2, `MkPoint x` is therefore not an *lpat*, and so `(MkPoint x)` is not an *apat*, and so `m@(MkPoint x)` is not an *apat* (and so not produced by *pat* → *lpat* → *apat*).

Answer (score 0):

> I can partially apply [a constructor] to one argument then apply that to the second.
>
> ```
>    thisPoint = ((MkPoint x) y)          -- partially apply the constructor
> ```

There's another way to achieve that without parens, also I can permute the arguments

```
thisPoint = MkPoint x $ y
thisPoint = flip MkPoint y $ x
```

Do I expect I could pattern match on that? No, because `flip`, `($)` are just arbitrary functions/operators.

> I want to grab the constructor and first arg as an as-pattern, ...

What's special about the first arg? Or the all-but-last arg (since you indicate your real application is more complex)? Do you you expect you could grab the constructor + third and fourth args as an as-pattern?

Haskell's pattern matching wants to keep it simple. If you want a binding to the constructor applied to an arbitrary subset of arguments, use a lambda expression mentioning your previously-bound var(s):

```
mkPy = \ x5 -> MkPoint x5 y1          -- y1 bound as per your q
```